# Para que serve realmente o GitHub?

Tags: github

Vejo muitas pessoas falando sobre ele, mas não sei a real importância do GitHub.

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre o *github* em particular ou envolve algo com o *git* também?

Comment: É por que não sei nada sobre ele,queria saber qual a utilidade dele

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Github é um site e serviço que fornece `GIT` gratuito e pago e tem interface para gerenciamento WEB, sem precisar instalar um cliente GIT.

Para entender o Github é preciso entender o serviço que eles fornecem
, e no caso o serviço é o `Git`.

`Git` é um sistema de controle de versão distribuído e um sistema de gerenciamento de código fonte, ele são como "protocolos" para trabalhar com repositórios, semelhante ao SVN.

O desenvolvimento de software contém muitas etapas e geralmente é necessário ter um histórico do que foi feito e poder até reverter.

E para gerenciar um git você precisará de um cliente para isto, geralmente usamos o git via linha de comando, que pode ser encontrado em:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Mas para facilitar existem os com interface gráfica:

- https://desktop.github.com
- https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Dentre muitos outros em: https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Pense que você tem um projeto grande e algo começou a falhar na ultima modificação, você pode olhar código por código até descobrir aonde falhou, ou simplesmente buscar no ultimo histórico do `Git` e ver exatamente o que você mudou através do *diff*

Outro objetivo de se usar Git é trabalhar com vários programadores, você conseguirão mesclar modificações gerenciar os *branchs* e saber exatamente o que o outro fez, remotamente também.

Claro que muitos desenvolvedores por ai trabalham com Git de maneira que pode ser complicada, pois geralmente todo mundo é tem controle absoluto sobre o "master", então todos commits se misturam e a trancos e barrancos as pessoas vão usando o Git, quando muitas vezes o ideal seria ter alguém que fosse o controlador principal, aquele que aprova e compara as coisas, mas isso é algo mais amplo para se falar e/ou explicar.

---

### Github e o open-source

O [@jefferson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) me recordou de um detalhe, apesar de não ter haver com a pergunta, é interessante dizer que o Github é bastante popular devido aos projetos open-source e o vinculo com outras ferramentas/serviços como:

- [packagist](https://packagist.org) para `composer`
- [MyGet](https://www.myget.org) (pode integrar github com nuget, npm, etc)

Existem muitos softwares que usamos hoje, como Angular, Vue, jQuery, Laravel, etc que são **versionados** no Github, ou seja o source esta lá e as modificações, correções, históricos e algumas distribuições (na aba *Release*) também são feitas pelo Github.

---

### O Github não é o único que fornece GIT

Github não é o único site que fornece GIT gratuito, exemplo também:

- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com) - **Nota:** tem repositórios privados ilimitados
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) - **Nota:** tem repositórios privados ilimitados, mas só permite 5 usuários
- [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net) - **Nota:** fornece Git, SVN, mercurial e Bazaar

---

Além do sistema de versionamento GIT existem outros como:

- [**SVN**](http://subversion.apache.org)
- [**mercurial**](https://www.mercurial-scm.org)
- [**Bazaar**](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/)

Comment: muito obrigado,tirou todas as minhas dúvidas

Comment: Devo ressaltar duas coisas para o leitor dessa resposta: (1) o GitHub tem uma pegada social muito, mas muito forte e legal; permite você seguir pessoas e repositórios, tem um feed tipo Facebook (mas apenas atividades de pessoas/projetos, sem fofoca). (2) o GitLab permite ter repositórios fechados gratuitamente, infinitos deles, já o GitHub oferece isso apenas na versão paga.

Comment: Guilherme, aproveitando o bonde da pergunta, se o maior objetivo do GitHub é o `Git`, não seria melhor fazer backups? Pois assim terá os arquivos para recuperar, caso haja alguma modificação que venha a prejudicar. Não?

Comment: @Thiago que backup? Sabe como funciona o cliente-git? Ele baixa copias pro seu computador e através do historico pode fazer rollback, não precisa de backup

Answer (score 0):

Para entender a importância do GitHub, precisa entender a [importância de um sistema de controle de versão](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-Sobre-Controle-de-Vers%C3%A3o).

> o controle de versão é um sistema que registra as mudanças feitas em um arquivo ou um conjunto de arquivos ao longo do tempo de forma que você possa recuperar versões específicas.

Não prenda o conceito de controle de versão à código-fonte. É muito útil entre programadores, porém eu poderia escrever um poema ou criar uma arte gráfica com ajuda de um sistema de controle de versão.

O GitHub é uma plataforma web de **hospedagem** de código (ou qualquer outra coisa, como poemas) que utiliza o [Git](https://git-scm.com) como sistema de controle de versão.

A grande importância do GitHub é o open source e a contribuição. Lá você pode hospedar seu projeto controlado pelo Git e diversas pessoas podem contribuir no seu projeto. Alguns projetos notórios que seguem esse modelo:

- o editor de código da Microsoft, o [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)
- o kernel [Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)
- o próprio [Git](https://github.com/git/git)
- a linguagem [Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) e o framework [Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails)

O GitHub re-moldou o que conhecemos hoje sobre contribuição e open source com o modelo web e utilizando Git.

- [Git - A Short History of Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-A-Short-History-of-Git)

Aprender Git antes de aprender GitHub é essencial. Mas como assim aprender GitHub? O GitHub tem alguns fluxos de trabalho além do Git. Os conceitos de pull requests, code reviews, issues e outros são exclusivos ao GitHub e vão além do Git.